# Using a file to configure multiple pages in Tkinter

Tags: python, class, python-2.7, tkinter, singleton

I want to create a program that can be maintained quite effortlessly, I have created 4 files as of now a `config`, `interTk`, `main` and `part1` (later expanding and adding part2, part3, etc.)

What my program does is store information in a config file and then use that information to display text in Tkinter.

**main:**

```
import config
import interTk
import part1
import part2

part1.p1()
part2.p2()
```

**part1:**

```
import config

def p1():
    config.str1 = 'hello'
    config.str2 = 'bye'
```

**part2:**

```
import config

def p2():
    config.str1 = 'hello 2'
    config.str2 = 'bye 2'
```

**config:**

```
str1 = ''
str2 = ''
```

**interTk:**

```
from Tkinter import *
import config

class interface:
    def __init__(self, root):
        root.title("Testing multiple files program")
        root.geometry("1200x700")

        app = Frame(root)
        app.pack(side = 'bottom')
        button1 = Button(app, text="Next")
        button1.pack()

    def text(self, string1, string2):
        Label(root, text = string1).pack(expand=1)
        Label(root, text = string2).pack(expand=1)

root = Tk()
string1 = config.str1
string2 = config.str2
int_obj = interface(root)
int_obj.text(string1, string2)
root.mainloop()
```

**The problem:**

When I run `main.p`y the tkinter application starts up but none of the text fields get updated. I have debugged the code and I have come to to decision that because interTk is imported before part1 it does not show the part 1 information. If I import the interTk file last I cant modify the labels because it uses the information passed by the last imported file.

What am I doing wrong? is there a better method of achieving my goal?

Answer (score 2):

## partx.py

```
import config

def p2():
    config.str1.set('hello 2')
    config.str2.set('bye 2')
```

## config.py

```
from Tkinter import StringVar
str1 = StringVar()
str2 = StringVar()
```

## intertk.py

```
...
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
import config
...
class interface:
    ... 
    def text(self):
        self.text1 = Label(root, textvar = config.str1).pack(expand=1)
        self.text2 = Label(root, textvar = config.str2).pack(expand=1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am getting an error from the config file saying tk is not defined.

Comment: `import Tkinter as tk`

Comment: I tried that before posting but I got the error File "E:\...\Tkinter.py", line 218, in __init__
    self._tk = master.tk
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tk'

Comment: ahh I see you need to initialize the root class first I guess

Comment: sorry to be a pest but ive tried everything I could and im still getting the same error. if i dont import tkinter as tk it says tk is not defined. if i do import it i get the error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tk'

Comment: it works fine ... i just tested a stripped down version